# Conditional formatting bases on text and current week number excel

Tags: excel

I am trying to get a conditional formatting to highlight columns that contain text and number based on current week.

Currently I have:

A sheet with top row full of "Week 1, Week 2....."

I use:

=A$1="week 42"

which highlights the column of week 42.

I want rather than to write "42" use this function to call current week: WEEKNUM(NOW())

so something along the lines of

=A$1="week WEEKNUM(NOW())"

this doesn't work and it is because I am missing something very basic in combining text and values, but I appreciate any help, and maybe there is even a smarter way of doing what I want that I am not aware of

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try changing you formula to:

```
="Week " & WEEKNUM(TODAY())
```